# Implements EventHandler from 2 classes

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have 2 classes that Implement 1 EventHandler. Its part of a fingerprint scanner API but I'm having some issue and I'm not sure if it is my fault in how i use the Implements.

Is it ok to have 2 different classes Implement the same EventHandler? Each class then uses the events differently within the class but it almost seems like there is some overlap that is causing some issues. I know this is hard to explain without posting code but since i can pinpoint the problem, idk what to post. My main point is, can you have 2 different classes Implement the same Interface? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is okay. You raise the event from the source and it can be handled (with an event handler) by any number of objects that have subscribed to that event and do whatever in the event handler.